# Getting Week Day via with getdate()

Tags: php, weekday

So I want to write a simple program & I want to check with if condition which day is it of the week. I am not quite sure how to get it right.

My date function looks like this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+6'); 
$info = getdate();
$hour = $info['hours'];
$day= $info['wday'];
```

And I'm trying to pull up the 'wday' value. However, I'm not getting it right. I read wday stores values as integers (Sunday = 0),

so when I write the code like this, it doesn't quite work.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+6'); 
$info = getdate();
$hour = $info['hours'];
$day= $info['wday'];

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $ehsir=$_POST['ehtesham'];


    if ($day=='3') 
        {
            if ($hour>=8 && $hour<=11 || $hour>=18 && $hour<=20) {
                echo '<div class="btn btn-success">Ehtesham sir is available </div>';
                }

        }
        else {
            echo '<div class="btn btn-danger"> Ehtesham Sir Is Not available </div>';}

}

?>
```

Comment: If the code isn't doing as you expect - what is `$day` set to when it runs? And have you checked to make sure that `$hour` is being set properly? (Additionally - if `$day == 3` is true, but the following if is not, you won't echo anything)

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do this stuff is by using the `DateTime` class.

```
$now = new DateTime('now');

$day = $now->format('w'); //    0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
$hour = $now->format('H');
```

See the docs for [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).